# Difficulty understanding a question involving $\int_{2x}^{3x}\frac{dt}{t}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> $\int_{2x}^{3x}\frac{dt}{t}$ does not really depend on $x$ (or $t$!).
>   Substitute $xu$ for $t$ and watch the limits on $u$.

Substituting $xu$ for $t$, we get $\int_{2x}^{3x}\frac{dxu}{xu}$. But the limits of the integral are $3x$ and $2x$. What does this question mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind this exercise is that, for $x > 0$, $$\int_{t=2x}^{3x} \frac{dt}{t}$$ represents the area under the curve $y = \frac{1}{t}$ on the interval $[2x, 3x]$; this interval has length $3x - 2x = x$, so the larger $x$ is, the longer the interval of integration.  But the starting and ending point also change as $x$ larger, and so, how does the area under the curve change as a function of $x$?  What is surprising is that **it doesn't** change at all:  $x$ does not affect the area under the curve.  It so happens that the change in the area under the curve as you move the interval is exactly counterbalanced by the change in area as a function of the interval's width.

See the animation below.  It shows the described area as a function of $x$, and you can convince yourself that the shaded region does look like it is in fact of constant area.

[image]

The computation to demonstrate this is by choosing the substitution $t(u) = xu$, where here $x > 0$ is a fixed constant; then $dt = x \, du$, and we obtain $$\int_{t=2x}^{3x} \frac{dt}{t} = \int_{u = 2}^3 \frac{x \, du}{xu} = \int_{u=2}^3 \frac{du}{u},$$ since the factor of $x$ cancels out.  Now, this is not terribly intuitive, but from a geometric perspective, what we have done with this substitution is to perform a scaling transformation on $t$ such that $t = 2x$ maps to $u = 2$, and $t = 3x$ maps to $u = 3$:  this corresponds to scaling the horizontal axis by a factor of $x$.  In doing so, we change the differential length $dt$ also by a factor of $x$, so $dt = x \, du$.  And the function also changes in the same way; i.e., $\frac{1}{t} = \frac{1}{xu}$.

Answer (score 3):

The integral is simply $\int_{2x}^{3x}\frac{1}{t}dt = \ln(s)|_{2x}^{3x} = \ln(3x)-\ln(2x)$. You can just treat $2x$ and $3x$ as constants, there is no need to make the substitution.

As pointed out by Brenton in the comment below, the above further reduces to $\ln\left(\frac{3x}{2x}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$.

Comment: You can take this a step further and note that $\ln(3x)-\ln(2x) = \ln \frac{3x}{2x} = \ln \frac{3}{2}$

Comment: @Brenton:  that step is needed to show that the result does not depend on $x$.  With the answer, this is exactly what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the questions is saying to use u substitution.  As a quick notational fix, remember that when making a substitution for $t$, you must also adjust $dt$.  In this case, $t=ux \implies dt = d(ux) = x\cdot du$.  Also, when making a substitution you must also change the limits of integration.  So, making the substitution, we have $\int_{2}^{3}\frac{1}{xu}xdu = \int_{2}^{3}\frac{1}{u}du$ since the $x$'s cancel.  Thus, the answer is independent of both $x$ and $t$.